On stimuli control
everyone!
I have a very simple question (I think). Has anyone here done a psycholinguistics experiment? After having run my first experiment, I realized that what I had controlled to build the sentences in the first place wasn’t quite right. In other words, some sentences (the target ones) were lengthy compared to the others. Some are reasonably controlled. Some aren’t. The thing is that it has been hard to find the participants to respond. There’s no way I can start it all over. Has anyone gone through that already? If so, could you please share how to get it somewhat fixed? Thanks a lot!

I’m voting to close this question because there is not enough context or examples.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Unfortunately, there's no real way to change the stimuli after the experiment has been done. All that work has to be done before they're presented to the subjects.
But, every experiment has some variables that aren't controlled. The best option I can see at this point is to acknowledge it: mention that the lengths of the sentences were not controlled. If someone thinks that could affect the outcome, they can try to replicate it with a new set of stimuli, and build off your results. Thus does science progress!

Thank you so much. It was comforting to read that.
